# SharePoint 2013 People Picker Field Should Not be current User

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, people-picker, validation-list-items

Would be very Grateful if you can kindly please help me out

I have a New Item Form with a `PeoplePicker` field with `Allow Multiple Selection` setting

The Requirement is the `Current User` who is filling the form should not fill his email address in the `PeoplePicker` field

The system should not allow him to save the `New Item` form

I don't know if this is possible.

Would be very grateful if I can get some assistance please.

i have try the below script which give the current user and The people picker field but its not working on pre save action

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">



var context = null;

var web = null;

var currentUser = null;

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetUserLoginName, "sp.js");

function GetUserLoginName() {

context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

web = context.get_web();

this._currentUser = web.get_currentUser();

context.load(this._currentUser);

context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod),

Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));

}

function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {

var today = new Date();

var peoplepicker=$("#Name_x0020_of_x0020__x0028_Recei_633edcdf-1dc4-4980-ab7e-94a503a6aca5").text(); //change ‘content’ to 

your people picker field ID.

if(peoplepicker!=this._currentUser.get_title())

{

alert(this._currentUser.get_title());

alert(peoplepicker);

 alert('current login user is not equal to people picker column');

Function.createDelegate(this, this.PreSaveAction));
}

}

function onFaiureMethod(sender, args) {

alert('request failed' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

}
});

 function PreSaveAction()
{

var peoplepicker=$("#Name_x0020_of_x0020__x0028_Recei_633edcdf-1dc4-4980-ab7e-94a503a6aca5").text(); //change ‘content’ to 

your people picker field ID.

if(peoplepicker!=this._currentUser.get_title())

{

alert('current login user is not equal to people picker column');

  return false;
   }
   else
   { 
return true;

 }
   }


</script>
```

can someone please help me am very new to coding thank you very much

Comment: Can you use Visual Studio and C#?

Comment: Related: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126618/person-group-type-column-not-listed-on-a-custom-lists-validation-settings-page

Answer (score 3):

As we know that `PeoplePicker` columns cannot be used in List Validation settings, So I don't think there is any OOTB option to achieve this requirement.

***So, what is workaround?***

Here I am sharing possible workaround, I haven't tried this requirement, but based on my work on `PeoplePicker` and customization of default `Lists Item Adding` form I am sharing the approach.

- You can overwrite the `PreSaveAction()` function and keep your required validations within this function. To know the working of `PreSaveAction()` please refer [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31330.sharepoint-using-presaveaction-function-on-custom-list-forms.aspx).
- You can always get the Current User ID using `_spPageContextInfo.userId`
- In the next step you can get the ID of users selected in the PeoplePicker field by writing some JavaScript stuffs and get the `ID` of selected users.
- Now you can compare this `IDs` and if match found it means that current user is selected in `PeoplePicker` field, so just `return false` at the end of the `PreSaveAction()` function. It will prevent page to add new item.
- You can either use `Content Editor WebPart` to put the code or you can directly edit the new form in SharePoint Designer.

Let me know if you need some more assistance.

Comment: Hello Sir - Thank you very much -i will try to implement it -
the Article you provide me very Good thank you very very much